# How to access arithmetic operators in javascript as functions?

Tags: javascript

What is the idiomatic way of writing something like the following but in `javascript`:

```
# in python
import operator
def foo(f, a, b): return f(a,b)

foo(operator.add, 2, 3) # returns 5
foo(operator.mul, 2, 3) # returns 6
```

--EDIT

I don't have a particular penchant for names "add", "mult", etc. In `R` for example, there is a plain vanilla backtick operator to get to a primitive. And before that, `sh`.

For me this was a quesiton of a more expressive approach for writing a code, and having run time efficiency or at least avoiding unnecessary run time burden. Why would I not want to avoid the cost of a function call?

This does not mean I have not taken your suggestions. I actually have, dear strangers :) But I also want my code to run faster if there is a workaround, esp. when it comes to an inner loop.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such thing as operator overloading in javascript. Try C++ :D

Comment: operator ＝ { add: function(a, b) { return a + b; } }

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira hehe but really I am not trying to overload them, merely wanting access. I feel this should be exposed via the `Math` library

Comment: Operators (again AFAIK) are core features of EMCA engine. They aren't 'accessible' by any means. Or maybe I didn't understand what you mean by 'wanting access'. The only access to this you can get is reading js engine source code.

Comment: And Math is a library for special math functions. It doens't contain the basic js operators. Here is the reference to Math:https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira in python, they aren't really either. those are just alias for something akin to `def mul(x, y): return x + y`

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent of `operator` in javascript and you can't overload operators in javascript like you can in Python. Still, functions are first class objects, so you can create a function similar to the one you posted. You just need to create your own `add` `mul`, etc.:

```js
let operator = {
    add(a, b) {return a + b},
    mul(a, b) {return a * b}
}

const foo = (f, a, b) => f(a,b)

console.log(foo(operator.add, 2, 3)) // returns 5
console.log(foo(operator.mul, 2, 3)) // returns 6
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can just create reusable functions that returns arithmetic calculations for you.

E.g. If you want a function for addition, you can create a reusable function like this:

```
function add(a,b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

The same way works for other kinds of arithmetic calculations:

```
function mult(a,b) {
    return a * b;
}
function subtr(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}
function divd(a,b) {
    return a / b;
}
```

This reusable function can then be called with parameters and it will return the calculated result of the parameters.

```
add(25, 75); // will return 100
subtr(76, 64); // will return 12
mult(15, 20); // will return 300
divd(300, 60); // will return 5
```

You can use the same approach as above for any other kind of arithmetic calculation too.

Answer (score 0):

```
var operator = {
  add: function(a, b) { return a + b; },
  mul: function(a, b) { return a * b; }
};

var foo = function(f, a, b) { return f(a, b) };
```

Then you can do this:

```
console.log(foo(operator.add, 1, 2)); // 3
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own `add` function that takes an arbitrary number of operators, and pass the functor to the `foo` function like you have in python.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21712944)

Comment: @Rafael I disagree, my answer is equivalent to the ones that are being upvoted, except that they provide the answer in code, and I provide the answer in text.

Comment: Please read [answer].